# How to fix QT6WebEngineCore.dll not found when running my pyside6 app?

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I created an app with pyside6 on my mac and it works fine, but i'm trying to compile my code on windows and it is giving me this error. Everything else works except the web viewer.

[image: here is the error]

Comment: Is that the *exact* error you're getting? How did you install PySide6? (Please note, with all due respect, that pointing out your age or experience is irrelevant to questions here on StackOverflow: we just try answer to questions as impartially as possible, knowing those aspects won't change anything).

Comment: I installed with pip install pyside6, i saw some thing about clang and tried to follow the steps, but not sure how to verify if i did it correctly

Comment: Please answer *both* questions: [edit] your post and provide the *exact* traceback of the error (if you're using an IDE, run the script from a command prompt).

Comment: I posted a picture of the error, when I run from the command prompt no error is output, all that happens is the error is displayed in a popup, thanks for the help

Comment: When you say "I'm trying to compile my code on windows", do you mean that you're running the python script, or that you're creating an executable with pyinstaller or other utilities?

Answer (score -1):

Do these steps:

1. Uninstall completely Anki app in your system with "youruninstaller" app
2. Setup Anki app version Qt6 **without changing the installation path** in your system
3. Restart your system
4. use it

Notice: **Don't** change the installation path during installation.
I had this problem and solved it by up instructions.

Comment: OP doesn't mention Anki. What makes you think that's related?